# NSArray and NSInteger Comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

NSNumber *j = @(1);

for(id i in array) {

    if ([i isEqual:j])// always executes an else..I don't know why
    {
        NSLog(@"This object is matching %@",i);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"This Object is missing %@",i);
    }
    j = @([j intValue] + 1);
}
```

the code always executes the else. I don't know why. I want to check the array elements whether some missing in a list or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `NSString`s from your array with the `NSNumber` `j`, so the comparison always fails

One way would be to use the `stringValue` of `j` instead:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"];

NSNumber *j = @(1);

for(NSString *i in array)
{
    if ([i isEqualToString:j.stringValue])
    {
        NSLog(@"This object is matching %@",i);            
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"This Object is missing %@",i);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me..Thanks sir..!

Comment: You are welcome. We do thank by accepting/up-voting the answer on SO though.

Comment: Could it be more interesting, I don't know if that's the author wants, but to compare NSInteger instead? For instance, comparing `@"01"` with `@(1)` should returns FALSE. If so: `if([[i integerValue] == [j integerValue])`.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting strings in your array using `@"..."`, but you should put in integers:

```
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10, nil];
```

Comment: @PreetGur then please accept either my or shallowThought's answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer which helped you more.

Comment: did it ..You both have cleared my doubts..only one can get..so I gave him.

Comment: Good idea in another way also I upvoted your answer too.